# How can I convert a class that has a super call to a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following:

```
import { Immutable, ImmutableStore, useStorePersistence } from 'signalstory'

import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

export type TId = string | number

export type TRegistration = {
   id: TId
   mrn: number
   vn: number
}

export class Registration {
   id = nanoid()

   mrn = 0
   vn = 0
}


export class RegistrationUiState {
   id: TId = nanoid()

   isSelected = false
}

export type TRegistrationState = {
   id: TId

   domain: TRegistration
   ui: TRegistrationUIState
}

export class RegistrationState {
   id: TId = nanoid()

   domain: TRegistration = new Registration()
   ui: TRegistrationUIState = new RegistrationUiState()
}

export class RegistrationStore extends ImmutableStore<TRegistrationState> {
   constructor() {
      super({
         name: 'RegistrationStore',
         mutationProducerFn:
            produce as unknown as MutationFn<TRegistrationState>,
         // enableLogging: !environment.production,
         initialState: new RegistrationState(),
         plugins: [
            useStorePersistence({
               persistenceKey: 'RegistrationStore',
               persistenceStorage: localStorage,
            }),
            ...environment.defaultStorePlugins(),
         ],
      })
   }

   store: Immutable<TRegistrationState> = this.state()
}
```

How could I convert it into a function?

Comment: Why do you even have to convert it? You can transpile it and since you've tagged this with TS, then it might be as simple as changing your target output in TS config. However, that does seem like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to begin with.

Comment: My use case requires it to be a function, NOT a class. I have looked at https://www.xolv.io/blog/dev-notes/how-to-pass-a-class-to-a-function-in-typescript/, but unfortunaely it does not explains my use case requirement.

Comment: Please explain your use case (include a  code example)

Comment: Does `const fn = () => new RegistrationStore()` not work? I find it *very strange* that the requirement is to change from class syntax to a function.

Comment: I am using Angular 17. It has a new inject() function that allows moving away from a facade to using individual exportable/importable function. For this to happen, the above use case will have to used. This article explains better what I am trying to accomplish [Goodbye NgRx Facades. Hello Standalone Functions](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/goodbye-ngrx-facades-hello-standalone-functions-7b7606c01659)

Comment: So, this has very little to do with the language itself, it's rather framework-related. Although, with that said, I'm looking through the article your requirement still doesn't match. What it suggests is "*Now that we no longer require a constructor to utilize DI, we can now create more modular reusable stand alone functions.*", so I don't think you're supposed to convert this class to a constructor function, you're supposed to re-do it with standalone functions and injection.

Comment: I agree. Maybe you would like to suggest an alternative to my request that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: Does it work to convert this to the old prototypical way? maybe make a wrapper function that inlines all the necessary classes and returns an instance??

Comment: Based on the article lhe posted, he needs to completely decouple the 2 prototypes, by using for...in or Object.assign or by getOwnPropertyNames. and basically create a function from ground up that has no ties to its super

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that doesn't depend on external libraries (unless your question is *about* these libraries, in which case you might want to tag it appropriately) and which doesn't have any undeclared types or values (for example, `TRegistrationState`).  Right now if I copy and paste your code into my IDE I get a slew of errors you're not asking about, which makes it very hard to work on.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what exactly you want, you want the old prototypical way of writing the extended Class? then it should look like this:

```js
const functionVersion = function(u, w){
      const instance = Reflect.construct(this.__proto__.__proto__.constructor, arguments, new.target);
      instance.p = 3;
      return instance;
    }

    const proto = functionVersion.prototype = Object.create(Whatever.prototype);
    proto.constructor = functionVersion;
    proto.publicMeth3 = function(){
      return this.publicMeth() + " ha-ha-ha";
    }
```

But do not forget that technically Classes are functions too (typeof Whatever is "function"). So I do not know if that clarifies a bit.

Beware that you still need to call the above with `new`, if you want to negate `new` that make a wrapper function that calls the target function with the `new` and returns the instance.

```js
//a class
class Whatever {
  constructor (u, w) {
    this.u = u;
    this.w = w;
  }
   
  #privMeth () {
    return this.u + 1;
  }
  
  publicMeth () {
    return this.#privMeth()
  }
}

//sub class that extends its super
class myExtend extends Whatever {
  constructor (u,w) {
    super(u, w);
    this.p = 3;
  }
  
  publicMeth3() {
    return this.publicMeth() + " ha-ha-ha"
  }
}
const whateva = new Whatever(1,2)
console.log(whateva.publicMeth());

const extended = new myExtend(1,2);
console.log(extended.publicMeth3(), extended.publicMeth()); //watch this line

//functional version of the extended class above
const functionVersion = function(u, w){
  const instance = Reflect.construct(this.__proto__.__proto__.constructor, arguments, new.target);
  instance.p = 3;
  return instance;
}

const proto = functionVersion.prototype = Object.create(Whatever.prototype);
proto.constructor = functionVersion;
proto.publicMeth3 = function(){
  return this.publicMeth() + " ha-ha-ha";
}

const extended2 = new functionVersion(1,2);
console.log(extended2.publicMeth3(), extended2.publicMeth()); //this line should be same as above
```